# Autosuggest Search results using multiple, specific object properties using ng-model and filter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ngmodel, angularjs-ng-model

Here's the JS for a simple, Angular autosuggest:

```
var app = angular.module('typeAhead', []);

app.controller('TestCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.things = [
        { name: "foo", description: "not just any foo" },
        { name: "bar", description: "a bar, in so many words" },
        { name: "gronk", description: "gronk was a wildcat before he was a patriot" },
        { name: "fleebles", description: "i dunno. fleebles just rolls off the tongue for me" },
        { name: "sepulveda", description: "i think 'sepulveda' is a real word with a real meaning" },
        { name: "crinkle", description: "crinkle, since 2008" }
    ];

    $scope.selected;

    $scope.choose = function(thing) {
        $scope.selected = thing;
        $scope.searchForm.$setPristine();
    }
});
```

...and the html:

```
<body ng-app="typeAhead" ng-controller="TestCtrl">

    <form name="searchForm" novalidate>
        <input type="text" ng-model="selected">
        <span>{{selected.description}}</span>
    </form>

    <div ng-if="selected">
        <div class="result" ng-repeat="thing in filtered = (things | filter:selected)" ng-click="choose(thing)">{{thing.name}}</div>
    </div>

</body>
```

This seems like it's working at first, with 2 problems while typing:

1. type some letters, then clear everything, and the full list shows up as results. Expected behavior would have no results if there's no search text
2. the search is polling both thing.name and thing.description, which is good, but I need it to prioritize name matches over description matches

There are also 3 new problems once a selection is made:

1. The suggestions don't disappear
2. The textfield shows `[Object object]`
3. The model is blown up, so subsequent searches don't work

If I change the input's `ng-model` to `selected.name`, making a choice fixes the text display, but then it's searching on name only.

Here's the plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/BcyfGnTGW6NFpf9jm7Mq?p=preview

It's obvious to me that there's a lot of power available by piping into a filter, but as far as I can tell they incinerated the documentation and offed the poor schlep who wrote it, so I have no idea what options and approaches are available, either strategic or syntactic.

Please don't suggest that I use UI-Bootstrap's Typeahead directive; it's awesome, but my example here is greatly simplified from the needs of my actual project, and UI-Bootstrap doesn't accommodate some of my custom needs.

Comment: Check Typeahead directive from Angular Bootstrap https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

Comment: Dmitri, I meant to add "please don't suggest ui-bootstrap's typeahead" to the end of the question, but I simply forgot to (I'll fix that now). My example here is actually greatly simplified from my actual project; ui-bootstrap's typeahead doesn't accommodate some of the other custom functionality that I need.

Comment: did you got solution finally? this is simple Angular task, I would make a directive for that

Comment: Not exactly. I've taken a different approach, using — you guessed it — UI-Bootstrap. It's really limited, but I'm living with its limitations and using custom results templates. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are using your search input field with the `$scope.selected` variable as the ng-model (which is at this point a string literal) and then, after calling the`choose(thing)` function - the `$scope.selected` becomes an object. This is why your input then shows `[object Object]`.

So the first thing is to decouple the search input field and your object where you hold your selected item. Your search form gets its own model: searchText.

```
<form name="searchForm" novalidate>
  <input type="text" ng-model="searchText">
  <span>{{selected.description}}</span>
</form>
```

The next thing is your filter. I have updated your ng-repeat to the following:

```
<div ng-if="searchText">
  <div class="result" ng-repeat="thing in things | filter: {name: searchText}" ng-click="choose(thing)">
    {{thing.name}}
  </div>
</div>
```

To explicitly search only for the name fields you already may have noticed the property selection on the `filter: {name: searchText}` - which in turn just filters for the name property matching your input's value.

Here's the [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/kr6rphU2Cg4hP5DbKXxV).

**UPDATE** due to the from grilchgristle Jul 1 at 22:09

So then, I have introduced a new variable `isUserSearching` which is true when the users is changing the searchText. When the user selects an entry, then `isUserSearching` is set to false - which then, hides the search results. As soon as the user changes something in the search field - the `isUserSearching` Variable gets set to true again and the search results appears. See plnkr.co/edit/UE7wFjAztUNFqzXpPEvu?p=preview.

Regarding the filter: 
you need to write your own filter which sorts your array first by the name, and then by descriptions. See docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter

Comment: Thanks! This is great, but your answer is only part of a solution. I can't limit the searches to `thing.name`, I just need the `name` matches to be prioritized over the `description` matches. Also, making a choice with your solution doesn't hide the search results.

Comment: @grilchgristle I removed my comment and updated my answer. Did it finally help you getting your problem solved?